# Big Cartel Contact Page - Captcha LIQUID Error

Tags: captcha, bigcartel

I changed a few minor things on my Contact page: I removed my address and phone number fields. Now, the Captcha is showing "liquid error" instead of loading.

I also copied the whole contact page and pasted into the Cart form. I'm trying to customize the site so there is no real checkout, but rather you can only contact me to place an order.

They both show the same liquid error instead of loading a captcha, and click through to an error page if trying to send an email.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it possible to work around, and keep the Cart as a clone of the Contact page? I wouldn't mind if I had to erase the contact form and just added a link on a simple page to email me.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The liquid error is a result of pasting the contact form fields into the Cart page - that will only work properly when it's used on the built-in Contact page, and not anywhere else in a Big Cartel shop.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you so much for responding. Is there a way to fix just the Contact page so that it works again? Both the Contact page and the Cart (with the pasted Contact fields) have the liquid error.

shoplarry dot com

Comment: Looks like the link in your header to the Contact page is actually pointing to the URL "/contact-s" which is a custom page, and not the actual built-in Contact page. Since the form fields don't work on custom pages, you're getting the Liquid Error.